# A question about a recursive relation

Tags: nt.number-theory

let be $c(x)$ the function that counts the composite numbers less or equal to x. So for example $c(5)=1$.
The number $128$ is a record because no composite number m less than 128 generates more composite numbers applying this algorithm:
if m-c(m) is 1 or prime stop the algorithm. Otherwise 
if m-c(m) is a composite number $r$<$m$ you repeat the algorithm with $r$.
Number $128$, which is a record, takes five steps to reach a prime number applying the above algorhitm. $128\rightarrow32\rightarrow12\rightarrow6\rightarrow4\rightarrow2$. So $128$ is a "record" because every integer less than $128$ takes less than 5 steps to reach a prime with this algorithm. With Pari Gp i found that the records are $4,6,12,32,128,710,...$. I Call a(1)=4, a(2)=6, a(3)=12 the terms of the sequence. My question is why the terms of the sequence satisfy the recursive relation $a(n+1)=p_{(a(n)-1)}+1$? where p is the (a(n)-1)-th prime.
Any formal proof of that?
So for example $32=p_{(12-1)=11}+1$

Comment: Your function induces a partition (how many steps from 1) of the natural numbers, and the function is monotonic (preserves $\geq$) on each piece. Thus the least element of each piece maps to the least element of the next piece.  This is not a good question for this forum.  Gerhard "Better Places To Ask This" Paseman,  2019.04.02.

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman cam you explain?

Comment: Related question asked by the same user: [Math SE: An elegant way to define a sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3170629/)